# How to display text in row one and row two customer display pole

Tags: c#

Am developing a program for an eatery, what i want to achieve is to display the
 **number of items** purchased in row one 
and the **total cost** in row two but the result is not coming out as expect, please what am i missing out

```
Private void DisplayPole(){ SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
        if (!(Properties.Settings.Default.ComPort == ""))
        {
            using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort(Properties.Settings.Default.ComPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8))
            {
                byte[] bytetosend = new byte[2] { 0x0C, 0x0c };
                port.Open();
                port.Write(bytetosend, 0, 2);
                //port.Write('\0x0C');
            }
            sp.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.ComPort;
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Parity = Parity.None;
            sp.DataBits = 8;
            sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            sp.Open();
            //clear
            //sp.Write(Convert.ToString(chr(12)));
            sp.WriteLine("No of Item: " + lblTotalItem.Text +"\n" + "Total: " + lblTotal.Text);
            sp.Close();
            sp.Dispose();
        }}
```

Comment: What is it the output that you're getting?

Comment: Why are you posting the serial port code when you are having issues displaying data?

Comment: @jdweng It looks like the OP is "printing" to a display pole via serial port.

Comment: Break the WriteLine into two Writelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WriteLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.8)

> WriteLine(String, Object, Object)

Writes the text representation of the specified objects, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream using the specified format information.

```
 sp.WriteLine("No of Item: " + lblTotalItem.Text );
 sp.WriteLIne("Total: " + lblTotal.Text);
```

The default line terminator is a string whose value is a carriage return followed by a line feed ("\r\n").

You could also have used

```
sp.WriteLine("No of Item: " + lblTotalItem.Text + "\r\n" + "Total: " + lblTotal.Text);
```

Comment: thanks it works fine, everything is okay now I really appreciate